# LINQ Query returns nothing

Tags: linq-to-sql, c#-3.0

Why is this query returns 0 lines?

There is a record matching the arguments.

```
SomeDataContext db = new SomeDataContext(ConnString);

return db.Deafkaw.Where(p => 
      (p.SomeDate1 >= aDate && 
         p.SomeDate1 <= DateTime.Now) &&
      (p.Year == aYear && p.IsSomething == false)
  ).ToList();
```

Am i missing something?

On the Table Deafkaw

SomeDate1 = 20/4/2010 11:32:17
Year = 2010
IsSomething = False

...besides other columns im not interested in conditions.

I need SomeDate1 between the dates i give IsSomething = False and Year = 2010.

Comment: What is `Deafkaw`, what is the value of `etos`, what is the value of `aDate`, and what is the exact data in the object, row, whatever?

Comment: My guess is that there's really no record which actually matches your where expression.

Comment: can we see the data that you think matches?  otherwise we have to chalk this up to "select is broken"...

Comment: Edited, maybe its more clear to you now what is this

Comment: @gtas:  well, not really.  There's still no clue regarding the content of the Deafkaw data set, and its contents are pretty key in determining what's wrong with your where conditions.

Comment: What are you providing for `aDate` at runtime?

Comment: I guess I suggest you fake this with a collection of objects which have values representative of your database.  Then run the query against that collection.  Then you can post the code which contains both the data and the query conditions.  It'd be much more straightforward to help you at that point, IMO.

Comment: How are you calling the method?

Comment: That was surprise. Adding var queryResult = theQuery.ToList() and return queryResult worked. Strange is other similar methods for another table where i ask similar conditions working in return....

Answer (score 3):

You aren't assigning the result to anything so it is being discarded. Try this:

```
var results = db.Deafkaw.Where(p => 
         (p.ImerominiaKataxorisis >= aDate && 
          p.ImerominiaKataxorisis <= DateTime.Now) &&
         (p.Year == etos && p.IsYpodeigma == false)
     ).ToList();
```

Update: you changed the question so now I'm not sure that this is the correct answer. Can you post the code where you call this method?

Comment: Oh, I just assumed that he just wasn't including an assignment in his message.

Comment: Basically .ToList() returns in a method.

Comment: @gtas: I am as surprised as you are. But it's good you have solved your problem.

Answer (score 2):

It is difficult to answer your question without any additional information. Checking the following points may help you to find the problem:

- If you remove `Where` clause and write `Deafkaw.ToList()`, what do you get?
- What is the value of `aDate` and `etos`?
- Can you double check the condition? Do you require that all subconditions hold at the same time? Are there any such data if you print entire `DeaFkaw` data structure?
- Can you try removing some sub-conditions to see if that gives you some results?

Comment: If i use Deafkaw.ToList() i get the data from the table properly, i need all these conditions to hold at the same time as you mean al are true...in a meaning, removing subconditions, still dont return what i need.strange isn't it

Comment: So, are you saying that if you write for example `Deafkaw.Where(p => p.ImerominiaKataxorisis <= DateTime.Now).ToList()`, you still get 0 results? Is that true for all sub-conditions (e.g. `IsYpodeigma == false`?), What happens when you write `Deafkaw.Where(p => true).ToList()`? Does that return some results?

Comment: I don't know why but i had to introduce a variable and return this variable to work!!! Other similar methods working direct in return statement.

Comment: That sounds weird. Could you edit your question and show the difference? Perhaps somebody could explain the behavior :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Deafkaw.Where(p => (p.ImerominiaKataxorisis >= aDate && p.ImerominiaKataxorisis <= DateTime.Now &&
            p.Year == etos && p.IsYpodeigma == false)).ToList();
```

Comment: why would that matter?  removing those parens is not going to affect the logic, they're all &&

Comment: Yeah, my bad.  For some reason I misread the operator precedence and had this in my brain (p => (a && b)) && (c && d).  But && beats => :)

Answer (score 0):

Use SQL profiler. Look at the sql query that is generated. Run the sql query manually and see if you get back any records.

Comment: You could also just set the `Log` property of your data context: `db.Log = Console.Out;` will output the query and bind parameters to the console, for example.